# PHP DOMDocument loadHTML error

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, domdocument

It's returning

> ( ! ) Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Misplaced DOCTYPE declaration in Entity, line: 3 in C:\wamp\www\source.php on line 8

The code:

```
<?php

    $url = "http://www.some-plain-html-website.com";

    $content = file_get_contents($url);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

?>
```

For some reason it wont parse $content. If i make content a string like $content = ""; and i parse it by element tag name it works no problem however if i give it the return of file_get_content() method it yields that error.

The documentation for file_get_contents() says it returns a string but for some reason its not working i even tried $content = (string)file_get_contents($url);

Same thing thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html page you are trying to grab is malformed. The document type declaration must be the first line of a document. You could try cutting the first two lines off of the content before loading it with `loadHTML()`.

Comment: Look through the PHP documentation for how to manipulate strings.........................

Answer (score 10):

In many cases it is advisable to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before `$dom->loadHTML($content);`

This way a warning will not be thrown, and the page is loaded anyway.